# Loading a random texture in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Suppose I have 10 objects and I want for each object to be given a texture picked for me randomly out of a pool of 10 textures. How do I go about that for this mesh object?

```
for(var int = 0; int <= 10 ; int++)
  { var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var testMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: loader.load('images/image1') });
    var testGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 50, 50);

    testSphere = new THREE.Mesh(testGeo, testMat);
    testSphere.position.set(distance, 100, 100);
    scene.add(testSphere); }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all of your texture-images are named in a numeric/sequential manner, you could do:

```
...
var testMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: loader.load('images/image' + THREE.Math.randInt(1, 10) ) });
...
```

If not, then you'd make a list of filenames in a manner similar to this, and choose a random value from the list:

```
var texturesList = [
    'images/image1',
    'images/some-other-image',
    'images/yet-another-image',
    ...
    'images/10th-image'
];
...
...
var randIndex = THREE.Math.randInt(0, texturesList.length - 1);
var randTexture = loader.load(texturesList[randIndex]);
var testMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: randTexture });
...
```